# How to use Chrome DevTools to find memory leak in NodeJS/Express route

Tags: node.js, express, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I have two routes in my NodeJS/Express App that seem to leak memory. I made some snapshots with Chrome DevTools but don't have any idea how to link that data to my code.

[image]

[image]
(Those snapshots (2 to 8) where taken about 3 minutes apart while I regularly was calling the routes from a script)

Route 1:

```
router.post('/riverwaterlevel', verifyBearerToken, async (req, res) => {
 
let uploadedData = req.body;

for (const element of uploadedData) {

    let latestRWLofUUID = await RiverWaterLevel.findOne({ uuid: element.uuid }).sort({ timestamp: -1 });
    
    if (latestRWLofUUID) {
        if (latestRWLofUUID.value !== element.value) {
            let newData = new RiverWaterLevel({
                uuid: element.uuid,
                station: element.station,
                water: element.water,
                timestamp: element.timestamp,
                value: element.value
            });

            await newData.save();
            newData = null;
        }
    } else {
        let newData = new RiverWaterLevel({
            uuid: element.uuid,
            station: element.station,
            water: element.water,
            timestamp: element.timestamp,
            value: element.value
        });

        await newData.save();
        newData = null;
    }

    latestRWLofUUID = null;
    
};

uploadedData = null;
res.json({});
```

});

Route 2:

```
router.post('/ais', verifyBearerToken, async (req, res) => {
//console.log(req.body);
let codedMessage = req.body.message;
const binaryMessage = decodeAisMessageToBinary(codedMessage);
if(binaryMessage.length === 6 * codedMessage.length){
    //console.log('Decoding to binary successful!');
    const messageType = decodeMessageTypeFromBinary(binaryMessage);
    //console.log(messageType);
    let timestamp = req.body.timestamp;
    const mmsi = decodeMmsiFromBinary(binaryMessage);
    if (messageType === 'dynamic') {
        const navigationStatus = decodeNavigationStatusFromBinary(binaryMessage);
        const speedOverGround = decodeSpeedOverGroundFromBinary(binaryMessage);
        const positionAccurancy = decodePositionAccuracyFromBinary(binaryMessage);
        const position = decodePositionFromBinary(binaryMessage);
        const courseOverGround = decodeCourseOverGroundFromBinary(binaryMessage);
        const trueHeading = decodeTrueHeadingFromBinary(binaryMessage);
        const blueFlag = decodeBlueFlagFromBinary(binaryMessage);
        let dynamicMsg = new AisVesselPosition({
            timestamp,
            mmsi,
            navigationStatus,
            speedOverGround,
            positionAccurancy,
            position,
            courseOverGround,
            trueHeading,
            blueFlag
        });
        await dynamicMsg.save();
        dynamicMsg = null;
    } else if (messageType === 'static') {

        let existingDataForMMSI = await AisVesselData.find({mmsi});

        if(existingDataForMMSI.length === 0){
            const name = decodeVesselNameFromBinary(binaryMessage);
            const size = decodeVesselSizeFromBinary(binaryMessage);
            const dimensions = decodeVesselDimensionsFromBinary(binaryMessage);
            let staticMsg = new AisVesselData({
                timestamp,
                mmsi,
                name,
                size,
                dimensions
            });
            await staticMsg.save();
            staticMsg = null;
        }
        
        existingDataForMMSI = null;
    }

    timestamp = null;
}

codedMessage = null;
res.json({});
```

});

Do you see any heavy mistakes in my code or can give me a hint how to link those snapshots to my code to find the leak(s)?